# Using NSPipe with NSTask to simulate command line input

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm writing a very simple GUI tool for a command line app. It only has 2 buttons. **Connect** and **Quit**.
In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I run the following

```
NSPipe *pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
writer = [pipe fileHandleForWriting];

NSTask *runTask = [[[NSTask alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *exefile = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
                     stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"vpngui"];
[runTask setLaunchPath: exefile];

NSString *exeDir = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSArray *pargs;
pargs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: exeDir, nil];
[runTask setArguments: pargs];
[runTask setStandardInput:pipe];
[runTask launch];
```

Then when the **Connect** button is clicked the following line of code is run

```
writer writeData:[@"Connect" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

and for the **Quit** button

```
writer writeData:[@"Quit" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Somehow the command line app never gets the Connect and Quit commands

Comment: Try adding a newline to either of the written strings... It is not uncommon for shell pipes to be buffered on newlines.

Comment: Use an `NSLog()` statement instead and see if anything happens or set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The data is probably buffered.

Try forcing to flush the file handle by calling the [`synchronizeFile:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/synchronizeFile) method:

> **synchronizeFile**
>
> *Causes all in-memory data and attributes of the file represented by the receiver to be written to permanent storage.*

Comment: Adding [writer synchronizeFile];

Results in:
[NSConcreteFileHandle synchronizeFile]: Operation not supported

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem and 
[closeFile:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileHandle/closeFile) works for me.

**closeFile:** to indicate that you have finished writing.

But next time you want to write you'd have to create a new fileHandle instance because the old one has been closed.